# How to show git log without date information

Tags: git

My current git log will show relative date information,

How to disable it ?

```
603f78e - Merge branch 'feature/add_category_collection_generators' into develop (2 days ago) 
ee235d6 - add category collection models (2 days ago)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if changing the setting log.date changes your log date display:

```
log.date
```

> Set the default date-time mode for the log command.
>   Setting a value for `log.date` is similar to using `git log's --date` option.
>
> Possible values are
>
> - `relative`,
> - `local`,
> - `default`,
> - `iso`,
> - `rfc`, and
> - `short`

Try for example:

```
git config log.date short
```

The goal, of course, is to keep using `git log`, not `git log` with options, and a `git log` alias.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reformat output with just short hash and subject

```
git log --oneline --pretty="format:%h - %s"
```